# Check checkbox after button click in other state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have 2 states - register and rules. In register i have checkbox "Agree with terms". In rules state i have button agree. If i click agree in rules, state must change to register and the checkbox in register must be checked.

This is register

```
<md-checkbox id="rules" class="blue myriad circle" ng-model="check" ng-change="changeAgree()" style="margin-bottom: 0px"></md-checkbox>
    <label id="rule_link" class="gray" style="width: 220px; line-height: 24px">
        Susipažinau ir sutinku su <u class="white" ui-sref="rules">taisyklėmis</u>
    </label>
```

This is rules

```
    <md-button class="md-raised blue-dark-button white" ng-click="agree()">Sutinku</md-button>
```

Controller

```
$scope.agree = function () {
            $scope.check = true;
            $state.go('register');
        };
```

Comment: Is the checkbox in other controller and other view? Because if so, you have to pass through parameters in the state, or through a service...

Comment: One controller, but different states

Answer (score 0):

Use  ng-checked to toggle the check

```
<md-checkbox ng-checked="check" id="rules" class="blue myriad circle" ng-change="changeAgree()" style="margin-bottom: 0px"></md-checkbox>
    <label id="rule_link" class="gray" style="width: 220px; line-height: 24px">
        Susipažinau ir sutinku su <u class="white" ui-sref="rules">taisyklėmis</u>
    </label>
```

if the scope of the button is different from the scope of the checkbox then you need a service to bind the values between them

Comment: If i use ng-checked then the checkbox can't be checked or unchecked, his like disabled

Comment: @JaraSkuder this should not happen,is there any error when you do this?

Comment: In console no, but idea says "ng-checked is not allowed here"

Comment: remove ng-model from your checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ng-model` try using `ng-checked` in your checkbox.

Comment: If i use ng-checked then the checkbox can't be checked or unchecked, his like disabled

Answer (score -1):

Ok i get it. I must make check variable not in scope, but in rootScope. Then it works perfectlly.

```
$scope.agree = function () {
            $rootScope.check = true;
            $state.go('register');
        };
```